# Utilizar Middleware na Integração de Sistemas

Tags: java, integração

Na empresa onde eu trabalho, precisamos integrar nosso sistema desktop, o qual possui um banco de dados local com um sistema que estará rodando em um servidor cloud. O nosso cenário é de 2000 clientes realizando uma integração assíncrona.

A aplicação retaguarda vai expor os serviços de integração utilizando rest.

Os nossos clientes vão possuir uma aplicação que executa tarefas agendadas consumindo os serviços de integração.

A duvida é utilizar um Middleware ou não:

Opção 1: A aplicação Cliente consome diretamente os serviços do retaguarda.

Opção 2: Utilizar uma aplicação Middleware, onde o sistema cliente consome um único serviço que adiciona as mensagens em uma fila de integração. O Middleware  fica responsável em consumir a fila e integrar com os serviços da aplicação retaguarda.

Comment: As duas abordagens são viáveis e dependem muito de outros aspectos que não estão na sua pergunta e que possivelmente nem teriam como estar mesmo por serem onerosos demais para se obter e disponíveis somente com o sistema já em avançado estado de desenvolvimento, tal como relatórios detalhados acerca de testes de carga. Ambas as soluções parecem ser muito boas e provavelmente serão equivalentes na maior parte dos casos realistas, só podendo demostrar diferenças reais em cenários bem específicos.

Comment: Olá, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Olha, não querendo sair muito do assunto, nem ser chato, nem nada, e ainda correndo o risco de estar errado, mas se esta pergunta se refere ao mesmo sistema [desta outra aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184194/227) e se este for algum sistema crítico, do qual empresas ou pessoas realmente dependem dele, eu aconselho fortemente que os responsáveis consultem diretamente um arquiteto para ajudar nas decisões. Parece um caso complexo, cheio de incertezas e com poucas informações disponíveis. O risco de falha é gigantesco.

Comment: 1º parte:
@utluiz, muito obrigado pela resposta, em relação a arquitetura ela já esta definida:

1º Integrador: Vamos ter uma aplicação executando nas lojas que monitoram uma tabela de fila de integração, essa tabela é mantida pela aplicação da loja.
O integrador transforma os dados em Json, e consome um serviço rest disponibilizado pelo middleware que adicionam as mensagens em uma fila.  O integrador controla a
prioridade do envio da informação entre cadastros e movimentação.

Comment: 2º parte: 

2º Middleware: Consome a Fila de entrada enviando as mensagens para seus destinatários. Essa aplicação ainda vai possuir uma camada de interface para que a equipe de suporte(1º nível) 
consiga visualizar problemas de integração.

3º Serviços: Os serviços serão os responsáveis por receber as informações através do formato JSON e persistir as mesmas no banco de dados. Esses serviços serão dividido em microservices

4º Banco de Dados: Vai ser um único banco com o controle de tenant.

Comment: 3º parte:
5º Vamos ter algumas Interfaces  que consomen os serviços: painel de Controle, Relatorios...

Em relação as perguntas no Stack Overflow é que comos o @VictorStafusa comentou, na fase de analise do projeto não conseguimos obter algumas respostas(performace, teste de carga)
disponíveis somente com o sistema já em avançado estado de desenvolvimento. Então as duvidas surgem e postamos aqui para tentar alguma resposta que ajude a somar ao projeto.

Answer (score -2):

Utilizar um middleware orientado a mensagens é uma ótima alternativa, pois garante maior desacoplamento e escalabilidade devido à sua natureza assíncrona.

Comment: Utilize um middleware e um broker orientado a mensagens amigão, lembre-se se sua solução começar a complicar e vc ver nela a necessidade de orquestração use um ESB